# Metro bundler not working after react-native upgrade

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have upgraded the react-native from 0.62.2 to 0.64.1 and also react to 17.0.1, but I am facing some build issue for both android and ios, the build is successfully and is getting installed on both the simulators but it's not opening and also the metro bundler fails with the below issue

error Cannot read property 'dependencyExtractor' of undefined.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dependencyExtractor' of undefined
at /Users/ss/rn/ui/node_modules/metro-config/src/loadConfig.js:269:42
at Array.reduce ()
at mergeConfig (/Users/ss/rn/ui/node_modules/metro-config/src/loadConfig.js:246:18)
at Object. (/Users/ss/rn/ui/metro.config.js:54:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Process terminated. Press  to close the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed, it was due to my metro.config.js file, I have removed all specific configurations

Comment: I have the same issue. What should I do ?

Comment: For me the issue was using `mergeConfig` in `metro.config.js`, I removed that and export only the config itself without merging it with the default config.

Comment: That is a great solution

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're using `module.exports` to export the config. I accidentally attempted to `return` it.